# How to compare 2 data frame column by column and show the difference only in rows along with values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frame and need to compare between them  column by column as column names remain constant, and show the only difference value along with column name in rows.
for example, I have attached 2 tables with the values show casing the difference and result should be as 3rd image.

I have tried with multiple ways and was able to get the Id and column names of difference but unable to get the values corresponding.

[image: df1=1st march]

[image: df2=2nd march]

[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for join together first:

```
df = (pd.concat([df1.set_index('ID').stack(), 
                 df2.set_index('ID').stack()], axis=1, keys=('1st','2nd'))
        .rename_axis(('ID','Attr'))
        .reset_index())
```

And then filter out same values:

```
df = df[df['1st'].ne(df['2nd'])]
```